# Dúvidas sobre o armazenamento de valores em uma variável

Tags: c, while

Estou tendo problemas para entender este especifico while loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
    }
}
```

O resultado de uma execução é este:

```
$ ./teste 
teste
teste
teste1
teste1
teste2
teste2
teste3
teste3
```

Como pode-se ver eu declarei **'c'** como sendo uma variável do tipo **int**, ou seja deveria armazenar apenas números, porém ao fornecer como input a string **'teste'** o programa funciona normalmente, então provavelmente eu deixei passar alguma coisa ou não estou entendendo como variáveis em **c** funcionam, então se alguém puder por favor explicar ou me apontar na direção, para que eu possa entender por que isso acontece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em [c](/questions/tagged/c), uma variável do tipo `char` é um inteiro de apenas um único byte. Se ele vai ser interpretado graficamente ou numericamente vai depender do contexto.

No caso, ao chamar [`getchar`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/), você está pedindo algo da entrada padrão que internamente a função retorna com a informação de um byte. Na descrição da função ele fala inclusive do porquê ser um inteiro o retorno:

> The return type is int to accommodate for the special value EOF, which indicates failure

Em tradução livre:

> O tipo de retorno é `int` para acomodar para o valor especial `EOF`, que indica falha

De modo geral, C trabalha sem muitas preocupações com relação aos tipos de dados inteiros, convertendo de um para o outro indiscriminadamente. Quando a conversão é de um tipo de menor tamanho para maior tamanho, diz-se que o tipo sofreu uma *promoção de inteiro*.

A função [`putchar`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putchar/) diz o seguinte sobre o seu argumento:

> The int promotion of the character to be written.
>   The value is internally converted to an unsigned char when written.

Que traduzindo fica:

> A promoção `int` do caracter a ser escrito.
>   O valor é internamente convertido para um `unsigned char` quando escrito.

Então, o que aconteceu aqui que deu certo no seu código é que o caracter recebido pela entrada padrão sofreu uma promoção inteira internamente, antes de ser devolvido pelo `getchar`. Então você passou o valor promovido adiante para a função `putchar`, que espera exatamente um valor promovido e, então, o converte para um caracter sem sinal e o imprime.

Comment: No segundo parágrafo, você disse "entrada padrão que internamente a função retorna com a informação de um byte", o que você quis dizer com "informação de um byte"?

Comment: [Daqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types), `signed char`: do mesmo tamanho que `char`, um inteiro entre `[-128, 127]`; `unsigned char`: do mesmo tamanho que `char`, um inteiro entre `[0, 255]`. Só precisa de um byte para guardar a informação. No caso, o valor 257 é o `EOF` para indicar fim da leitura